# Removing outliers with Exponential moving avergae using python

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I have a crop price dataset I am trying to implement prophet prediction model. but before that I want to replace outliers. I am currently detecting the outliers using 10% and 90% quantile technique. and replacing it with the 10% and 90% value (maximum and minimum value allowed). but now I want to replace those outliers with the Exponential weighted moving average. for example data values are [1,2,3,4,5,6,20,7,8,9,10] want to replace 20 with it EWMA value.
how I can do that?
As you can see in the original graph there is an outlier in the year 2011. "I just want to replace that peak value by the value of EWMA."
[Dataset description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oklBx.png)

[Original graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aac5x.png)

Comment: Can you describe what the Exponetially weigthed moving average is? Without a formula it will be hard to do anything here..

Comment: [link](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/trading-investing/exponentially-weighted-moving-average-ewma/)
You can refer this link as comments do not allow to put a picture

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) to compute an [exponentially weighted moving operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).

There are several parameters to consider depending on your exact use case. Here is a short example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,20,7,8,9,10])

s.ewm(com=2).mean()
```

output:

```
0      1.000000
1      1.600000
2      2.263158
3      2.984615
4      3.758294
5      4.577444
6     10.037882
7      8.984140
8      8.647332
9      8.766963
10     9.182782
dtype: float64
```

visual example:

[image: ewma]

##### masking outliers:

you can compute the absolute difference between the original Series and the ewma and use a threshold to `mask`:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,20,7,8,9,10])
s2 = s.ewm(com=2).mean()
outliers = s.sub(s2).abs().gt(2)
s3 = s.mask(outliers, s2)
```

output:

```
0      1.000000
1      2.000000
2      3.000000
3      4.000000
4      5.000000
5      6.000000
6     10.037882
7      7.000000
8      8.000000
9      9.000000
10    10.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The main concern is I just want to replace the outliers values with the EWMA not the entire timeseries.

Comment: @DarshilShah but you detected the outliers with another method?